# How to get records that exist in one MySql table and not another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, outer-join

I need to write a query that returns the records that exist in one MySql table and do not exist in the other table.  In this example, I want all of the wafers that exist in the wafer_log table that do not exist in the bt_log table.

Here is the current query I'm using:

```
    SELECT wafer_log.wafer, bt_log.id AS blid, wafer_log.id AS wlid 
    FROM bt_log RIGHT OUTER JOIN wafer_log
    ON bt_log.waferid = wafer_log.wafer
    WHERE wafer_log.wafer IS NOT NULL AND bt_log.id IS NULL;
```

My thought here was to get the wafer name from the table I care about as well as the ids for both of the tables and do an outer join on the wafer name.  From there, I wanted to see all of the results where wafer name was not null in wafer_log table and id in the bt_log is null.

I don't feel like the results look right though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is similar to the question marked as duplicate but not identical. As to the selected answer, yes it works however subqueries (NOT IN (SELECT)) degrade exponentially. A better response would be: `SELECT wafer_log.wafer, wafer_log.id AS wlid FROM bt_log LEFT JOIN wafer_log ON bt_log.waferid = wafer_log.wafer WHERE wafer_log.wafer IS NULL;` Iterate over bt_log and display any wafer logs that are not found.  Best results assume wafer_log.wafer and bt_log.waferid are indexed.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join to do this, assuming 'id' is your primary key you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT wafer_log.wafer, wafer_log.id AS wlid 
FROM wafer_log
WHERE wafer_log.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM bt_log);
```

Comment: This requires querying all rows of bt_log into the temporary table in memory. Not nice!